# Add select list text box and remove button on click of button

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I want to add a select list , textbox and remove button on click of the button and get value from every select list and text box i have added and store inside a hidden field i have created such as data, on change of select or value entered in textboxes i want that data to get store inside the hidden field.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
   <input type="hidden" id="locdata" value="{{ locdata|json_encode() }}">
   <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <div id="TextBoxContainer">
   <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
   </div>
   <br />
   <input id="btnGet" type="button" value="Get Values" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
            var div = $("<div />");
            div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
            $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
            $("select.locdata").select2();
        });
        $("#btnGet").bind("click", function () {
            var values = "";
            $("input[name=Budget]").each(function () {
                values += $(this).val() + "\n";
            });
            alert(values);
        });
        $("#location_1").on("click", function(){
            console.log('hii');
            var values = "";
            var e = document.getElementsByClassName("locdata");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].val();
            $("input[name=Location]").each(function () {
                values += $(this).val() + "\n";
            });
            console.log(strUser);
            console.log(values);
        });
        $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
            $(this).closest("div").remove();
        });
    });
    function locdata(value){
        var locdata = jQuery.parseJSON($("#locdata").val());
        locdata.toString();
        var str = "<select class='locdata' id='location_1'>";
        for(var prop in locdata) {
            str+="<option value='"+locdata[prop].value+"'>"+locdata[prop].label+"</option>";
        }
        str+='</select><input name = "Budget" type="text"  value = "'+ value +'" />&nbsp;<a type="button" value="Remove" class="remove fa fa-minus-circle" ></a>';
        return str;
    }
    function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
        return locdata(value);
    }
</script>
```

[This is what i have done but cant get the data plz help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUFCN.jpg)

Comment: You are asking a bit much. If you narrow down your problem to a single specific issue and better describe what error/ problem you are having you are more likely to get a response.

Comment: i just want a select list to get created on click of button and get data of all the select list i can do the rest it dynamic select list..